# title in graphic with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
\section{graph}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmax=7.5, xmin=-5.5,
        ymax=3.5, ymin=0,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis equal image=true,
        xlabel={\(a \in  \mathbf{Set}(\{\mathbf{mis}_i(X)\}_{i=1}^6 )\)},
        ylabel={\(f_a^{\text{ass}}\)},
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
            anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
            anchor=south,},
        xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
            ]
    \addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates
        {(-2,1) (0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (4,1)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the output is [image]

How can I do to have the following output:

[image]

or the following output:

[image]

????? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you should consider putting this in as a `figure` environment, though this is not strictly necessary.  You can then add a caption in the normal fashion (`\caption{...}`).  You can optionally rename "Figure" to "Graph" by using `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Graph}`.  The figure would be numbered along with all the other figures as appropriate.

However, to simply box the graph, you can wrap the `tikzpicture` inside `\fbox{ ... }`.

The caption can be explicitly specified as you indicate by adding the text directly, as indicated below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}
\section{graph}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Graph}
{\centering\fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmax=7.5, xmin=-5.5,
        ymax=3.5, ymin=0,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis equal image=true,
        xlabel={\(a \in  \mathbf{Set}(\{\mathbf{mis}_i(X)\}_{i=1}^6 )\)},
        ylabel={\(f_a^{\text{ass}}\)},
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
            anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
            anchor=south,},
        xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
            ]
    \addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates
        {(-2,1) (0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (4,1)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \par\vspace{1ex} % To add appropriate space
    Graph 1.0.1 --- Proof of 1.0 % Caption
\par}

\end{document}
```

[image: graph]

Comment: You can also consider to use `\captionof` from `caption` package: I think is much more easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for a `figure` environment, csltr's answer is good, but if you just want to frame and label your graph you can use `current bounding box` node. Once `axis` environment is closed, the `current bounding box` node contains the whole graph (axis, labels, graph title, ...). You can `draw` it if you want a frame and you can add more text nodes or label using it as reference. Take a look at two commands after `\end{axis}` in next code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
\section{graph}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmax=7.5, xmin=-5.5,
        ymax=3.5, ymin=0,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis equal image=true,
        xlabel={\(a \in  \mathbf{Set}(\{\mathbf{mis}_i(X)\}_{i=1}^6 )\)},
        ylabel={\(f_a^{\text{ass}}\)},
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
            anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
            anchor=south,},
        xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
        ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
            ]
    \addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates
        {(-2,1) (0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (4,1)};
    \end{axis}
% Comment next line to suppress the frame
    \draw[ultra thick] ([shift={(-2mm,2mm)}]current bounding box.north west) rectangle ([shift={(2mm,-2mm)}]current bounding box.south east);
    \node[at =(current bounding box.south), anchor=north] {Graph 1.0.1 -- Prove 1.0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]